# DotNetNuke "Web Server Updated" event viewer message stopped scheduling process

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have scheduled one DNN scheduling process in Host=>Schedule section and it can take 3 to 4 hours to completed. But process can't able to completed because of "Web Server Updated" message popping up randomly in event viewer section and it restarts my application. It stopped scheduling process and forcing to restart scheduler. I'm using DNN version 07.03.02.

Do anyone knows what is the reason of this "Web Server Updated" message. Do I contact my hosting provider? OR Is it DNN problem?

Please review below screen shots.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjni9an5ajwghcq/2017-04-03%2011_16_44-Journal.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzhzv6tcvrq3z7b/2017-04-03%2011_16_44-Journal_1.png?dl=0

Comment: If it takes 3 to 4 hours to complete, putting it in DNN as a schedule might not be the best approach. Every time the AppPool gets recycled, the schedule is interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue would be due to the worker process restarting.  DNN Inserts the "Web Server Updated" log entry at the start of the application.

For processes running that long, I'd recommend moving them outside of DNN due to the inherent nature of web applications.  But if it is mandatory that it stay inside make sure that you have Always On enabled in IIS.  I'd also recommend using a monitoring or similar solution to ensure you have traffic all the time, at least every 10-15 minutes before the 20 minute process shutdown.

Note: Even with the best configuration possible, it is NOT guaranteed that your process will run for 3-4 hours without interruption.

Comment: I changed it to console application and scheduled it on Windows Task Scheduler. Thanks for your answer.